# How can I configure a multiline comment section in Formik with React Native?

Tags: react-native, textarea, multiline, formik

I'm trying to add a multiline comment section to a Formik form in React Native.  I've added height  component but that doesn't work.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`<TextInput multiline minHeight={100}`